# Firebase not configuring iOS

Tags: ios, database, xcode, swift, firebase

When I tried to add the command `FIRApp.configure()` to my `viewDidLoad()` method in the ViewController I kept getting:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase


class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
//        if UserDefaults.standard().string(forKey: "username") != nil {
//            performSegue(withIdentifier: "userInfoSegue", sender: self) }
    FIRApp.configure()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the call to this method in `AppDelegate`.

From the documentation, we can see that `configure` should be called after the application is launched. So it would make the most sense to put it in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` because that method is called when the application launches!

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    FIRApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

Comment: I got it working! It seems that adding FIRApp.configure() to the application function that is already provided doesn't work. I just copy-pasted yours and it worked

Comment: However, I keep getting the NSException again whenever I try to use Firebase anywhere

Comment: The app seems to configure but when I try to make an instance of a database reference then the app crashes

Comment: I don't think accessing the database is relevant to this question. You can read through the official documentation on how to do it. If it still doesn't work, Google it. If you can't find anything, ask another question.